# Can't get php contact form to work

Tags: php, forms

I have a webpage that has two contact forms and the second one is working fine but I can't seem to get the first one to work. I am fairly new to php. Thanks in advance for the help. Here's the html:

```
        <h3>Message Us</h3>
        <form action="?" method="POST" onsubmit="return saveScrollPositions(this);">
            <input type="hidden" name="scrollx" id="scrollx" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="scrolly" id="scrolly" value="0" />
            <div id="msgbox1">
                <label for="name2">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder=" Required" />

                <label for="email2">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder=" Required" />

            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="" />

                <label for= "topic">Topic:</label>
                <select id="topic" name="topic">
                    <option value="general">General</option>
                    <option value="stud">Property Price Enquiry</option>
                    <option value="sale">Bull Sale Enquiry</option> 
                </select>
            </div><!--- msg box 1 -->
            <div id="msgbox2">    
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" colums="25" placeholder="Your Message?"></textarea>
                <p id="feedback2"><?php echo $feedback2; ?></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </div><!--- msg box 2 -->
        </form><!--- end form -->
    </div><!--- end message box -->
```

And here's the php:

```
<?php 

$to2 = '418@hotmail.com'; $subject2 = 'MPG Website Enquiry';

$name2 = $_POST ['name2']; $email2 = $_POST ['email2']; $phone = $_POST ['phone']; $topic = $_POST ['topic']; $message = $_POST ['message'];

$body2 = <<<EMAIL

This is a message from $name2 Topic: $topic 

Message: $message

From: $name2 Email: $email2 Phone: $phone

EMAIL;

$header2 = ' From: $email2';

if($_POST['submit']=='Send Message'){
    if($name2 == '' || $email2 == '' || $message == ''){
        $feedback2 = '*Please fill out all the fields';  
    }else {
        mail($to2, $subject2, $body2, $header2);
        $feedback2 = 'Thanks for the message. <br /> We will contact you soon!';
    } } ?>
```

For the saveScrollPositions I use the following php and script:

```
<?php

$scrollx = 0;

$scrolly = 0;

if(!empty($_REQUEST['scrollx'])) {

$scrollx = $_REQUEST['scrollx'];

}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['scrolly'])) {

$scrolly = $_REQUEST['scrolly'];

}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.scrollTo(<?php echo "$scrollx" ?>, <?php echo "$scrolly" ?>);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your HTML part i.e.

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

add attribute name also in this input type like this-

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" />
```

one thing more to correct in your php script is write-

```
$header2 = "From: ".$email2;  instead of  $header2 = ' From: $email2';
```

now try it.

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for the fix up in the header. I did notice that wasn't working on the other form either

Comment: Have you changed your input tag as I have showed in my answer? If yes then what is being shown in variable $feedback2 ?

Comment: Sorry it worked! I was missing a "" Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: what are you getting in php variable $feedback2 after submitting form ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you return in "saveScrollPositions" function? if you return false the form submit wont fire.

Comment: I edited my answer to included the "saveScrollPositions" function. And this function works fine for the second form but I did wonder if I had to make two "saveScrollPositions" functions. Thanks for your help ali.